# Calcular dias en una fecha dada por mes

Tags: php, laravel-5, carbon

Hola quisiera reflejar el numero de días de un trabajador ausente desde su fecha de ausencia bien sea utilizando [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com) o algo nativo en php, uso Laravel el ejemplo es este:

En la BD consulto el ausentismo que dicho trabajador posee

```
$ausentismo_anual_dias = $empresa->ausentismo()
->whereYear('fecha_ausente', Carbon::now()->format('Y'))
->get();
```

En un ciclo **foreach** quiero imprimir desde su fecha ausencia ejemplo

```
foreach($ausentismo_anual_dias as $row){
           //Aqui quiero calcular los dias de ausencias 

        }
```

**Nota** los dias de ausencia deben calcularse por **mes ejemplo** 
Este trabajador tiene ausencia desde la fecha dada **2018-10-06(Mes octubre)** a la fecha final del mes **octubre 2018-10-31** tiene **25 dias** ausente, entonces vamos a **noviembre  2018-11-01** a la fecha actual  **2018-11-05** tiene en ese mes **5 días transcurridos**  Todo eso debe recorrerse desde el ciclo

mostrándolo asi:

Octubre: 25 días ausente

Noviembre: 5 días ausente

Diciembre no debe mostrar ya que no estamos en ese mes por lo que debería de estar en 0 días

Espero puedan ayudarme en dicha solicitud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes generar las fechas que están dentro del rango de las ausencias. Puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```php
/**
 * genera fechas entre 2 fechas y las agrupa por periodo (año-mes)
 *
 * si until es nulo, se usa la fecha actual
 *
 * @param   string      $since   fecha desde con formato YYYY-mm-dd
 * @param   string|null $until   fecha hasta con formato YYYY-mm-dd
 * @return  array
 *
 */
function generateDates(string $since, string $until = null) {
    $dates = [];

    if (! $until) {
        $until = date('Y-m-d');
    }

    $since = strtotime($since);
    $until = strtotime($until);

    do {
        $period           = date('Y-m', $since); // para agrupar por periodo AÑO-MES
        $dates[$period][] = date('Y-m-d', $since);
        $since            = strtotime("+ 1 day", $since);
    } while($since <= $until);

    return $dates;
}
```

para ejecutar:

```
$dates = generateDates('2018-10-06', '2018-11-05');
// print_r(generateDates('2018-10-06'));
// Si no pasas el segundo parámetro se asume que es la fecha actual
```

Para mostrar los días por cada periodo debes recorrer el arreglo generado por la función ej:

```
foreach ($dates as $period => $date) {
    $days = count($date);
    echo "El periodo {$period} tiene {$days} días <br>";
}

/* output
El periodo 2018-10 tiene 26 días 
El periodo 2018-11 tiene 5 días
*/
```

Imprimo las salidas de lo que me genera la función:

```
print_r($dates);
/** output:
Array
(
[2018-10] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2018-10-06
        [1] => 2018-10-07
        [2] => 2018-10-08
        [3] => 2018-10-09
        [4] => 2018-10-10
        [5] => 2018-10-11
        [6] => 2018-10-12
        [7] => 2018-10-13
        [8] => 2018-10-14
        [9] => 2018-10-15
        [10] => 2018-10-16
        [11] => 2018-10-17
        [12] => 2018-10-18
        [13] => 2018-10-19
        [14] => 2018-10-20
        [15] => 2018-10-21
        [16] => 2018-10-22
        [17] => 2018-10-23
        [18] => 2018-10-24
        [19] => 2018-10-25
        [20] => 2018-10-26
        [21] => 2018-10-27
        [22] => 2018-10-28
        [23] => 2018-10-29
        [24] => 2018-10-30
        [25] => 2018-10-31
    )

[2018-11] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2018-11-01
        [1] => 2018-11-02
        [2] => 2018-11-03
        [3] => 2018-11-04
        [4] => 2018-11-05
    )

)
*/
```

Comment: Pero como le digo yo que a la fecha de octubre tiene 25 tanto días ausente @varTob

Comment: complementé la respuesta para que veas como obtener el detalle por días

Comment: **Hasta el momento solo me calcula un mes ** 
 foreach($ausentismo_anual_ene as $row){
            $dates = $this->generateDates($row['fecha_ausente'], Carbon::parse(Carbon::parse(Carbon::now()->year)->endOfMonth())->format('Y-m-d'));
            foreach ($dates as $period => $date) {
                $days = count($date);
                echo "El periodo {$period} tiene {$days} días <br>";
                dd($days);
            }
        }

Comment: ** Hasta el momento solo me calcula un mes ** 
@varTob Deberia de calcularme las fechas si tengo 2018-10-02 apartir de esa fecha hasta hoy calcular los dias por meses desde su fecha de ausencia

Comment: la función para generar las fechas la veo bastante sencilla.. toma 2 fechas: fecha inicial y fecha final, parte desde la fecha inicial sumando 1 día hasta llegar a la fecha final.. si necesitas modificar el formato de salida puedes cambiarlo dentro del do { } while(...); .. probaste la función por separado para ver lo que genera?? te recomiendo que hagas eso para que después la adaptes a lo que necesitas

Comment: +1 @varTob gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
@forelse ($ausentismo_anual_ene as $key => $row)
                                @php
                                    $period =    new DatePeriod(
                                    new DateTime($row['fecha_ausente']),
                                    new DateInterval('P1D'),
                                    new DateTime($row['fecha_alta']));
                                    foreach ($period as $key => $value)
                                    {
                                        $dias[] = $value->format('Y-m-d');
                                    }
                                $comprobar = new App\Helpers\ComprobarDiasAusente();
                                @endphp
                                        @foreach ($dias as $key => $dia)
                                            @php
                                                $dates = $comprobar->generateDates($dia);
foreach ($dates as $period => $date) {
    $days = count($date);
    echo "El periodo {$period} tiene {$days} días <br>";
}

                                            @endphp

                                        @endforeach

                                        @php

                                        @endphp
                                    @empty
                                        0,
                                    @endforelse
```

Logre imprimirlo pero me repite los dias de esta forma

```
El periodo 2018-10 tiene 16 días <br>El periodo 2018-11 tiene 6 días <br>
                                                                                    El periodo 2018-10 tiene 15 días <br>El periodo 2018-11 tiene 6 días <br>
                                                                                    El periodo 2018-10 tiene 14 días <br>El periodo 2018-11 tiene 6 días <br>
                                                                                    El periodo 2018-10 tiene 13 días <br>El periodo 2018-11 tiene 6 días <br>
                                                                                    El periodo 2018-10 tiene 12 días <br>El periodo 2018-11 tiene 6 días <br>
                                                                                    El periodo 2018-10 tiene 11 días <br>El periodo 2018-11 tiene 6 días <br>
                                                                                    El periodo 2018-10 tiene 10 días <br>El periodo 2018-11 tiene 6 días <br>
                                                                                    El periodo 2018-10 tiene 9 días <br>El periodo 2018-11 tiene 6 días <br>
                                                                                    El periodo 2018-10 tiene 8 días <br>El periodo 2018-11 tiene 6 días <br>
                                                                                    El periodo 2018-10 tiene 7 días <br>El periodo 2018-11 tiene 6 días <br>
                                                                                    El periodo 2018-10 tiene 6 días <br>El periodo 2018-11 tiene 6 días <br>
                                                                                    El periodo 2018-10 tiene 5 días <br>El periodo 2018-11 tiene 6 días <br>
                                                                                    El periodo 2018-10 tiene 4 días <br>El periodo 2018-11 tiene 6 días <br>
                                                                                    El periodo 2018-10 tiene 3 días <br>El periodo 2018-11 tiene 6 días <br>
                                                                                    El periodo 2018-10 tiene 2 días <br>El periodo 2018-11 tiene 6 días <br>
                                                                                    El periodo 2018-10 tiene 1 días <br>El periodo 2018-11 tiene 6 días <br>
                                                                                    El periodo 2018-11 tiene 6 días <br>
                                                                                    El periodo 2018-11 tiene 5 días <br>
                                                                                    El periodo 2018-11 tiene 4 días <br>
                                                                                    El periodo 2018-11 tiene 3 días <br>
                                                                                    El periodo 2018-11 tiene 2 días <br>
                                                                                    El periodo 2018-11 tiene 1 días <br>
```

Comment: @varTob esto pasa

Comment: creo que partimos mal, éste es el código que debiste compartir al realizar la pregunta..

Comment: tú ya estás generando las fechas que están dentro del periodo.. mi función hace lo mismo.. prueba lo siguiente:

Comment: $end = new DateTime($row['fecha_alta']);
    $end->modify('+ 1 day');
    $period = new DatePeriod(
        new DateTime($row['fecha_ausente']),
        new DateInterval('P1D'),
        $end
    );

    foreach ($period as $key => $value) {
        $dias[$value->format('Y-m')][] = $value->format('Y-m-d');
    }

    foreach ($dias as $k => $v) {
        $count = count($v);
        echo "El periodo {$k} tiene {$count} días <br>";
    }

Comment: @varTob Ya lo hago y te cuento

Comment: @varTob Me funciona pero no me ordena el array de meses desde enero a diciembre como haria para que se ordenara asi de esa forma Enero: 0 dias ausencia, Febrero: 3 dias, Marzo: 10 dias, y asi sucesivamente y disculpa la molestia.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85400/discussion-between-vdjkelly-and-vartob).

Comment: Excelente, lo que yo haría es cerrar esta pregunta y crear una nueva con la nueva consulta que tienes agregando todo el código que tienes hasta ahora, para no confundir las cosas

Comment: @varTob Okey la cierro entonces y formulo una nueva

Comment: @varTob Sabes que me di cuenta que no agrupa las fechas todo marcha bien si le pasas una fecha pero le le pasas dos fechas de dos trabajadores ausentes esta se repite ejemplo si tu tienes una ausencia en octubre y noviembre y yo tengo una a partir de 3 de noviembre en el arreglo que me enviaste se repite noviembre dos veces debería solo contar el numero de dias asi este mes se repita dos veces o hasta mas ya que no es un solo trabajador que se puede ausentar

Comment: quizas debes vaciar el array  $dias en cada iteración, puedes agregar antes de $period lo siguiente:  $dias = []; $period = new DatePeriod( .... .. al final me perdí, no se cual es la última versión de tu código

Comment: @varTob Este es el codigo es el mismo que em enviaste $end = new DateTime($row['fecha_alta']); $end->modify('+ 1 day'); $period = new DatePeriod( new DateTime($row['fecha_ausente']), new DateInterval('P1D'), $end ); foreach ($period as $key => $value) { $dias[$value->format('Y-m')][] = $value->format('Y-m-d'); } foreach ($dias as $k => $v) { $count = count($v); echo "El periodo {$k} tiene {$count} días <br>"; }